# Get the "Text" value out of "System.EventArgs objArgs"

Tags: c#, eventargs

As you can see in that screenshot in "objArgs" there is a property "Text". How can I reach that property?

[image]

Comment: Show the method signature

Comment: @Roman the only things I can select after the dot is "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType", "SetUnderConstruction" and "ToString"

Comment: @Roman hehe ye his answer works!

Comment: Sure, it's Jon Skeet ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast the args to `ToolBarItemEventArgs`, at which point you can access the `ToolBarButton` it refers to:

```
var toolBarArgs = (ToolBarItemEventArgs) objArgs;
switch (toolBarArgs.ToolBarButton.Text)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I would suggest *not* switching on the text. Instead, ideally set up a different event handler for each of your buttons. If you really can't do that, you can use:

```
var toolBarArgs = (ToolBarItemEventArgs) objArgs;
var button = toolBarArgs.ToolBarButton;
if (button == saveButton)
{
    ...
}
```

Or you *could* switch on the `Name` rather than the `Text` - I'd expect the `Name` to be basically an implementation detail, whereas the `Text` is user-facing and could well be localized.

Comment: Yes that's it thank you! I accept this answer in 7 min! It doesn't allow me right now.